# INF file generation for WinCE CAB wizard

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, cab

I am facing problem while generating CAB file. I want to customize the INF file generation depending upon what components I choose to package. At present, we need to modify the INF file manually to include/exclude the components. I would just like to know, is there any programmatic interface where I will give the paths of the components to be packaged and it will give me INF file. This file I will provide to cabwiz.exe to generate the CAB archive. I am searching this type of solution because I want to avoid VS installation on non-developer's machine.

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any "programmatic interface for INF generation", but that said, it would be pretty trivial to create one. [The INF format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms924764.aspx) is pretty straightforward with not a lot of sections or options, and many of which you can safely ignore.

I created a tool some time back that generated an INF that would parse a desktop file/directory tree and generate an INFo that would replicate the same tree on the device with the same files.  Basically you'd build the tree on the PC that you wanted on the device and the tool would read what you had, build an INF and then package it (I'd actually post the code, but I can't find it offhand). It took maybe an hour to write.